# Type casting of HTML Elements

Tags: html, typescript

I’m trying to get an element using `document.querySelector` function.

The element is a button, so if I do:

```
let mybutton: Element = document.querySelector(‘button.ok’);
mybutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (mybutton.disabled) 
    // TS linter returns "Property 'disabled' does not exist on Type 'Element'
```

So I can give my `button.ok` to a HTMLButtonElement:

```
let mybutton: HTMLButtonElement = document.querySelector('button.ok');
// TS linter returns "Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement'."
```

So how can I manage a button and its properties in TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to explicitly cast the object, rather than trying to implicitly cast it by setting it to a variable of a predefined type:

```
let mybutton = <HTMLButtonElement>document.querySelector('button.ok');
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in order to help the compiler determine the type of the variable.

```js
let mybutton: Element = document.querySelector('button.ok');
mybutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (isButton(mybutton)) {
        mybutton.disabled;
    }
})

function isButton(element: any): element is HTMLButtonElement {
    return (<HTMLButtonElement>element).disabled !== undefined;
}
```

You can see a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20mybutton%3A%20Element%20%3D%20document.querySelector('button.ok')%3B%0D%0Amybutton.addEventListener('click'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isButton(mybutton))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mybutton.disabled%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isButton(element%3A%20any)%3A%20element%20is%20HTMLButtonElement%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%3CHTMLButtonElement%3Eelement).disabled%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%20).

Comment: That's a neat approach! Although wouldn't the specific code you provided be incorrect? For example, it'd match a [TextArea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) as that has a disabled property too. Or am I getting mixed up?

Comment: it would indeed, in practice if  the only property you are interested in is the disabled one you could just make an interface with the property you are interested in and test for that. :) I can make an example for that too, although it would be pretty much the same.